# Python3.6 logging.getLogger("mylogger") within Tk.mainloop() not cachable

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, tkinter

I'm stuck into a terrifically surprising problem that I can't figure out.

We are talking about **Python 3.6.4** and **tkinter 8.6** and the built-in **logging** lib.

### First, here is "MyLogger" class:

```
# file: logger.py

import logging.handlers

GENERIC_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)-8s :: '%(name)s' :: %(module)s.%(funcName)s :: proc=%(process)d :: %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d)"


class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    """ Main logger """

    def __init__(self, level=logging.DEBUG, filehandler=None, consolemode=True):
        self.fmt = logging.Formatter(GENERIC_FORMAT)
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name='my_logger', level=level)

        if filehandler is not None:
            self.setup_filehandler(filehandler)

        if consolemode:
            console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            console_handler.setFormatter(self.fmt)
            self.addHandler(console_handler)

    def setup_filehandler(self, filehandler):
        file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
            filename=filehandler, mode='a', maxBytes=1e+7, backupCount=10)
        file_handler.setFormatter(self.fmt)
        self.addHandler(file_handler)
```

**Nota:** when instantiated, it creates a logger called 'my_logger'

### Then, my main application:

```
# file: main_application.py

from tkinter import Tk
import logging
import os
from logger import MyLogger
from myframe import MyFrame

# Logger main instance
logger = MyLogger(level=logging.DEBUG)


def MyFrameRunner():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("450x450+400+150")
    MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()


def main():
    # Set the filehandler for the main L6 logger
    logfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "MYTOOL.log")
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(logfile)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(logfile))
    logger.setup_filehandler(filehandler=logfile)

    # It logs successfully into sdterr and $SW_PATH/MYTOOL.log file !!
    logger.info("Let's go !!")
    MyFrameRunner()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Nota:** as mentionned, logger.info within main/main_application.py logs successfully into sdterr (StreamHandler) and $SW_PATH/MYTOOL.log file (RotatingFileHandler) !!

### Finally, MyFrame:

```
# file : myframe.py

from tkinter import *
import logging

# With the same name as defined in MyLogger class
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')


class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        logger.info("Here is my frame !!")
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

### And my problem:

With the above code, it's impossible to catch the logger called "my_loger" with the logging.getLogger('my_logger') into myframe.py.

There is *no error*, but there is **no "log"** neither into *sdterr* (StreamHandler) nor *$SW_PATH/MYTOOL.log* file (RotatingFileHandler).

**Question:** it is "normal" that within a Tk() mainloop, there is no way to "pass a logger" (in fact, to catch a logger)?

The only "log output" that I obtain is:

```
2018-10-29 17:03:32,871 :: INFO     :: 'my_logger' :: main_application.main :: proc=21484 :: Let's go !! (main_application.py:31)
```

Whereas I excepted:

```
2018-10-29 17:03:32,871 :: INFO     :: 'my_logger' :: main_application.main :: proc=21484 :: Let's go !! (main_application.py:31)
2018-10-29 17:03:xx,xxx :: INFO     :: 'my_logger' :: myframe.MyFrame :: proc=21484 :: Here is my frame !! (myframe.py:15)
```

Thank's a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Could be done by passing "logger" as one of MyFrame args:

Edit in **main_application.py**:

```
# file: main_application.py

from tkinter import Tk
import logging
import os
from logger import MyLogger
from myframe import MyFrame

# Logger main instance
logger = MyLogger(level=logging.DEBUG)


def MyFrameRunner():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("450x450+400+150")
    # Old: MyFrame(root)
    MyFrame(root, logger)
    root.mainloop()


def main():
    # Set the filehandler for the main L6 logger
    logfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "MYTOOL.log")
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(logfile)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(logfile))
    logger.setup_filehandler(filehandler=logfile)

    # It logs successfully into sdterr and $SW_PATH/MYTOOL.log file !!
    logger.info("Let's go !!")
    MyFrameRunner()
```

Edit in **myframe.py**:

```
# file : myframe.py

from tkinter import *
import logging
from logger import MyLogger

# With the same name as defined in MyLogger class
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')


class MyFrame(Frame):
    # Old: def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    def __init__(self, master, logger=MyLogger(), **kw):
        logger.info("Here is my frame !!")
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
```